# number of web application we should have in a medium size topology

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, topology, capacity-planning

what will correct answer of this question?
"How many web application we should have in a medium size topology in SharePoint 2010 farm?"

I understand the capacity planning recommendation. But the question is not clear to me.

Does it mean in medium topology only one web application is recommended? we should try with creating new site collections only?

Pl share your views.

Comment: Keep in mind that the recommended practice in SharePoint 2013 is to create Host Named site collections where possible. If you do this you keep your web app numbers down, and your solution more supportable & upgradeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to 10 separate web applications on a farm. How many you *should* have is really up to your business needs. If you need to have two separate URLs for two completely different aspects of your business, 2 separate web applications is a good way to go. It's also a good way to go if you need different access levels between the two configurations (i.e. one that is intranet only and can get away with NTLM and one that uses Forms Based Authorization on the internet).

All in all, the fewer you can get away with maintaining, the better. Eventually you'll have to upgrade your SP instance and there may well be a period of time when you're maintaining 2010 and 2013 (or 2013 and 2016) farms, etc. As always, of course, business needs trump everything else.